# Java implementation of stochastic indicator for finance

Tags: java, finance, stochastic

Hy,

I'm searching for an API/library offering an implementation of the financial stochastic technical analysis.

Does someone know a ready-do-use solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an open-source library for calculating technical indicators, give [TA-Lib](http://ta-lib.org) a go. Source code is available for .Net, Java and C/C++. The open-source version hasn't been updated since September 2007 though, and there is a paid for Excel version as well.

If you are working in a .Net environment and just want chart rendering, I think the [MSChart](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) control (purchased from Dundas by Microsoft) supports a small set of TA indicators.

If you want to implement the indicators yourself, the 'bible' that documents them is
[Technical Analysis from A to Z, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071363483) (affiliate link).

Answer (score 3):

I released a Java library for technical analysis: [ta4j](http://github.com/mdeverdelhan/ta4j-origins)

It comes with several indicators, including: Aroon, ADX, ATR, Bollinger bands, moving averages, parabolic SAR... and [stochastic oscillators](http://github.com/mdeverdelhan/ta4j/tree/ta4j-0.3/src/main/java/eu/verdelhan/ta4j/indicators/oscillators).

Comment: New repo https://github.com/ta4j/ta4j

Comment: Exceptional library. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some additional answers / information may be relevant from this question:

- [Quantitative finance/mathematical library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711941/214010)